# Better way to sum

Tags: c#, linq

i'm having problem summing items in a modular way.

I have this class:

```
public enum ReportType
{
  Worker,
  Management,
  Guest
}

public class Report
{
  public ReportType Type { get; set; }
  public int Lost { get; set; }

  public Report(ReportType typ, int los)
  {
     Type = typ;
     Lost = los;
  }
}
```

and a method that gets a list of `Report`, and should find out and return a list of `Report` with the biggest loss, plus some calculation according to that number.
i started the method:

```
public class ReportsManager
{
  public static List<Report> CalculateBiggerLost(List<Report> reportList)
  {
     int WorkerSum = 0;
     int ManagementSum = 0;
     int GuestSum = 0;

     foreach (Report report in reportList)
     {
        switch (report.Type)
        {
              case ReportType.Guest:
              {
                 GuestSum += report.Lost;
                 break;
              }
              case ReportType.Management:
              {
                 ManagementSum += report.Lost;
                 break;
              }
              case ReportType.Worker:
              {
                 WorkerSum += report.Lost;
                 break;
              }
        }
     }

     if (GuestSum >= ManagementSum && GuestSum >= WorkerSum)
     {
        // Doing some report
     }
     else if (WorkerSum >= ManagementSum)
     {
        // inner Check
     }
  }
}
```

but it's not good in case i'll might have another value in `ReportType` enum and then will have to rewrite the code, plus it's not so readable. i'm new to linq but i started to try and `GroupBy` using linq but got stuck when i got and answer to `reportList.GroupBy(x => x.Type);` and did not know what to do with it, as in what's the structure? how do i iterate it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the query that you want:

```
var results = reportList.GroupBy(r => r.Type)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(r => r.Lost));
int WorkerSum = results[ReportType.Worker];
int ManagementSum = results[ReportType.Management];
int GuestSum = results[ReportType.Guest];
```

This will work fine if you expect to have at least one report of each type. If it's possible that there are no reports of a give type you'd have to check for that first, like this:

```
int WorkerSum = results.ContainsKey(ReportType.Worker) ? results[ReportType.Worker] : 0;
int ManagementSum = results.ContainsKey(ReportType.Management) ? results[ReportType.Management] : 0;
int GuestSum = results.ContainsKey(ReportType.Guest) ? results[ReportType.Guest] : 0;
```

Or like this:

```
int WorkerSum;
int ManagementSum;
int GuestSum;
results.TryGetValue(ReportType.Worker, out WorkerSum);
results.TryGetValue(ReportType.Management, out ManagementSum);
results.TryGetValue(ReportType.Guest, out GuestSum);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int guestSum = reportList.Where(x=>x.Type==ReportType.Guest).Sum(x=>x.Lost);
int workerSum = reportList.Where(x=>x.Type==ReportType.Worker).Sum(x=>x.Lost);
int managementSum = reportList.Where(x=>x.Type==ReportType.Manment).Sum(x=>x.Lost);
```